# Json Database. I want to get a number from a json string and put it into a database.

Tags: python, sql, json, django, progressive-web-apps

I am making a PWA for a friend. the database has users and the users have json strings associated with them. I know that I can just ask the database for that user's Json in html or js, but I want to know if its possible to have the database look at that json String, and automatically divvy out the details in it to the database say every hour.

I know there is a simpler way of just putting the json string in the database under the user, then just parsing it when the user logs into the page and asks for it. just wondering if I can skip a step and just make the database auto update the json string into the DB itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use crontab to schedule tasks for your system to complete. Update the database information using one of these tasks. You may also use Celery, but crontab is easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that, never heard of those !